# Find Textboxes != "" Transfer them to a label with a "," between each

Tags: c#, wpf

I am looking for a solution
I have several TexBoxes
I would like to get the information when there is some and insert them in a label with a "," between each.
I had thought of a solution with Foreeach :

```
            List<TextBox> test = new List<TextBox>() { Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4, Test5, Test6 };
           
            if (test != null)
            {
            test .ForEach(("," + Result.Content.ToString());
            }
```

But he not work.
any body for help me please ?

Comment: You should use a MultiBinding.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use Join to join the strings and some linq

```
var ls = new List<TextBox>() 
{ 
    new TextBox() { Text = "test1" }, 
    new TextBox() { Text = "test2" }, 
    new TextBox() { Text = "test3" } 
};
var concat = string.Join(",", ls.Select(x=>x.Text));
Console.WriteLine(concat);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can select the contents from the textboxes where the value is not empty and then join these together with string.join. Then you will have to update the content of the label to this value. It would look something like this.

```
var textBoxes = new List<TextBox>() { Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4, Test5, Test6 };
var values = textBoxes.Select(x => x.Text).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
ResultLabel.Content = string.Join(',', values);
```